# Maximum value of an array

Tags: c, pointers

The program should find the maximum value of the array, but I'm facing an error I cannot fix.

I get the following error:

> invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'.

Replacing `int` by `float` works as expected.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void find_biggest(int, int, int *);
int main()
{
    int a[100], n, *biggest;
    int i;
    
    printf("Number of elements in array ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the values: ");
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    
    find_biggest(a, n, &biggest); //invalid conversion  from 'int*' to 'int'
    
    printf("Biggest = %d",biggest);
    
    return 0;
}

void find_biggest(int a[], int n, int *biggest)
{
    int i;
    *biggest=a[0];
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>*biggest)
        {
            *biggest=a[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a mismatch between your function prototype:

```
void find_biggest(int, int, int *);
```

And definition:

```
void find_biggest(int a[], int n, int *biggest)
```

Since you're passing the array `a` as the first argument, the definition is correct and the prototype is incorrect.  Change it to:

```
void find_biggest(int [], int, int *);
```

Or:

```
void find_biggest(int *, int, int *);
```

You're also passing the wrong type for the third argument.  You define `biggest` as an `int` pointer and are passing its address, so the given parameter has type `int **` when it expects `int`.  So change type type of `biggest` to `int`.

```
int a[100], n, biggest;
```

Answer (score 0):

The word find is a word reserved in langage C,you must avoid it

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[100], n, *biggest;
   int i;

printf("Number of elements in array ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("\nEnter the values: ");
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

biggest_array(a, n, &biggest); //invalid conversion  from 'int*' to 'int'

printf("Biggest = %d",biggest);

return 0;
}

void biggest_array(int a[], int n, int *biggest)
{
int i;
*biggest=a[0];
for(i=1; i<n; i++)
{
    if(a[i]>*biggest)
    {
        *biggest=a[i];
    }
}
}
```